# the limit of infinite product $(1+y)(1+y^2)(1+y^3)(1+y^4)\cdots $

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, products

I wonder if the function $(1+y)(1+y^2)(1+y^3)(1+y^4)\cdots, 0< y<1$, converges to some well-known function.

If we let $ (1+y)(1+y^2)(1+y^3)(1+y^4)\cdots  = \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+y^i) = 
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i y^i$ then $a_i$ satisfies the following relation: 
$$a_0=1, i > 0$$
$a_i$ is the the number of partitions $(b_1, \cdots , b_s) $ of natural number $i$ such that $\sum_{t=1}^s b_t =i$ and $b_t < b_{t+1}$. For instance $a_{10} = 9$

$$(1,2,3,4) \; (1,2,7) \; (1,3,6) \; (1,4,5) \; (1,9) \; (2,8) \; (3,7) \; (4,6) \; (10)$$

$a_{10}$ is like Ramanujan's function $p(n)$. Is there anything in number theory related with $a_i$? At any rate the infinite product converges the function we know well? That is to say, it is a

--------------------------Adding------------------------------------------------

I found the material :

Let $p(n) $ is a Ramanujan function. For instance p(4) =4 :

```
1+1+1+1 = 1+ 3  =2+2 = 2+ 1+1
```

$\sum^\infty_{n=0} p(n) x^n = \Pi^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{1-x^n}$

Here the convenience is $p(0)=0$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a simple closed function for $$\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+y^i)$$ but there are the alternatives $$ 1\left/\prod_{m =0}^\infty \left(1-y^{2m+1}\right)\right. $$ and $$ \sum_{k= 0}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{y^j}{1-y^j}.$$

[OEIS A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009) has more information.

Comment: +1 I had some difficulty reading your sentence, you are saying the three expressions are all equal, but none of them qualifies as closed form.

Comment: It is nice to notice that the equality of the first two expressions here is precisely the theorem of Euler.

Answer (score 3):

One extraordinarily beautiful result, due to Euler, is that the number of partitions of a number with odd parts is always equals the number of partitions of that number with distinct parts. Your $a_i$ is the latter.

This is the beginning of a beautiful part of combinatorics.

Comment: I do not understand the number of partitions of a number with odd parts. What is odd parts ?

Comment: @user37116:  You can decompose 7=1+1+5=1+3+3 and other ways, but not 7=1+2+4 because 2 and 4 are even.  You might start with [Wikipedia on partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: It is a partition with odd parts, not a number with odd parts.  Maybe clearer to say partitions of a number into odd parts.

Comment: excuse me could you repeat your Euler's theorem ? I don't understand what are saying. $7$ is actually equal to $1+2+4$