# Computing the limit of the sequence : $ x_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n} 1 + a^{2i} $

Tags: limits, infinite-product

The given sequence is $$ x_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n} 1 + a^{2i}  ~,~\mbox{  a} \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n  $.

I struggle finding something for $ a \in ]-1,1[ \setminus \{0\}.$ Do you have any idea ? 
For the other values, applying the criterea $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is sufficient.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214711/the-limit-of-infinite-product-1y1y21y31y4-cdots ?

Comment: not completely because you take only the even terms...

Comment: Just substitute $y = a^2$, then $1+a^{2i} = 1 + y^i$ ...

Comment: @MartinR but wait I don't understand the point. He is asking for an approximation, and I want the limit. Moreover the answer converge to the point that there is no good approximation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that when you develope the expression of $x_n$, you find this : 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} a^k $$
so then to compute the limit, you just have to compute the sum of a geometrical sequence.
Then it does converge for value of $a$ between $ ]-1,1[ $.